# "Upon" means "after" in this context

Tags: prepositions

We use **on / upon** in these sentences:

> Don't forget to call me **upon** reaching there.
>
> The recipe was deliciously awesome that everyone licked their fingers **upon** finishing it.

**upon** here means **immediately after.**

How **after** is different from **upon** in this context?

Can I use **upon** to mean **immediately after** in any situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **immediately after**, you could use **when** in these sentences, but not with the -ing form.  Your sentences (with minor edits):

> Don't forget to call me **when** you get there.
>
> The recipe was so delicious that everyone licked their fingers **when** they finished it.

Another reasonable option:

> Don't forget to call me **as soon as** you get there.
>
> The recipe was so delicious that everyone licked their fingers **as soon as** they finished it.

This doesn't sound sound as good in the second sentence, though, because "as soon as" has a nuance of urgency, and licking one's fingers after eating isn't exactly urgent.

Comment: Could you tell me about the use of "on" in this context.

Answer (score 2):

upon (or on) means: **at the time of reaching a place or doing something**.

- **Upon** reaching the house, we parked the car in the driveway and went indoors.
- **Upon** crossing the garden, he saw a rabbit in the bushes.

It is a literary word. People do not use it usually in conversations.

- Don't forget to call me as soon as you get there. [spoken language, no upon].
- Upon reaching the house, we forgot all about calling him. [written language]